# Change image to another after a certain time by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Javascript code

**Problem Statement**: I have a button and an image on page. When I click the button the image is replaced with another for a certain time (e.g. 3 minutes) and after time ends, image is replaced with initial image.

**Note**: I would like to achieve this without page refresh.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: So you want to look into setTimeout

Comment: Have you written any code yet, seen any errors?

Comment: Please attempt to write the code, and come back when you need help with your code.

Comment: Please undo your accept answer. I need to delete it. For your reference, I have created a fiddle with only script just as below. http://jsfiddle.net/fojmoyef/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_btn", function() { // This is how event binding should be done.
      // Change source of image here
      setTimeout(function(){
           // Reset source of image here
     }, 180000)
});
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: imho, I would refrain from giving OP any code without first him providing some—how do you know that he even understands the syntax of this bind?

Comment: Because you're doing OP's homework (not literal homework, but you're doing his research for him). Teach a man how to fish, etc. etc.

Comment: @AaronHarding - Well, I was course of explaining the answer, however, my initial answer is always the code with believe that OP is not naive.

Comment: @AaronHarding - Well, I feel this platform is for professionals so I differ from your opinion on this task as homework for someone.

Comment: Sure, but I would have just referenced setTimeout, click events, and so on .. and not written any code.

Comment: @AaronHarding - Well, I prefer to answer and explain things. That is my style of expressing and working with my juniors as well. Probably, I feel not the same for everyone here as down voting continues :)

Comment: You know something I'm sorry for ask this Question I've made a mistake by singed up in this website I don't even understand if I'm a professional why I would even ask ?! I just want someone to give me help that's it I'm not pleasing from anyone

Comment: @MohammaedAlAbed - You need not feel bad buddy. This platform expects even a newbie to post their effort and then professionals across the globe come to help. The main belief is "God helps those who help themselves". This is in a way correct. If you would have posted your code, you would have got positive response as well. Just forget about it. Stay focused on your job

Answer (score 3):

Wait people I know a lot of things about PHP , CSS and SQL and I've already created a website from the beginning but about Javascript I don't know a lot just the main definitions

Comment: You can refer to the ideas suggested by people here. Also, you can copy my answer as I am about to delete the answer in a minute Please note, the answer should be taken as reference and not to be copied blindly :)